# Pytest не видит файлы для импорта

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

День добрый. Имеется  структура проекта:

```
.main.py
    -src/json_wrapper.py
    -tests/test_json_wrapper.py
```

В test_json_wrapper добавлена конструкция

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
```

Дабы он смог импортировать враппер при запуске.

Проблема: при запуске pytest-a из директории tests - всё проходит успешно, но при запуске из корневой директории - он видит тесты, но не может импортировать в них файл json_wrapper

```
tests\test_json_wrapper.py:5: in <module>
    from src.json_wrapper import JsonWrapper
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Как сделать возможность корректного запуска pytest из любой папки?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в папках `src` и `tests` создать файлы с именами `__init__.py`. Это должно сказать pytest, что их родительский каталог *это директория с проектом*.

Далее для запуска тестов из родительского каталога используйте:

```
pytest tests
```

Из папки с тестами:

```
pytest
```

Answer (score 1):

`__init__.py` нужен в папках, чтобы можно было ее инициализировать как пакет, соответственно добавлять необходимые модули.
По этому надо создать их, просто пустыми.

Comment: чем ваш ответ отличается от ответа svmitin кроме краткости?

Comment: короче + рекомендация по создаю файла думал я..